# Why the clearing stays permanent in obstacle costmap, when 0 (overwrite) combination method is applied?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I am **clearing** some layers **markings** by a layer **with** a detected **object** to be cleared and the **problem** is that its' **clearing stay permanent** even when the object disappeares.

So here more detailed information:

---

The goal:

- **Erase** any **markings** on the costmap **under x_object** when it is **detected**
- Continue **marking** with laser layers **when** the **x_object** is **disappeared** or was **not present**

---

The actual results:

- The laser layers mark the obstacles. Perfect ! =)
- The x_object detected and overwrites (erases) the markings. Perfect ! =)
- The x_object disappeares (goes away) Perfect ! =)
- The laser layers do not mark anymore where was detected the x_object. Bad ! =(

---

I tried different observation_persistence values:

- 0.0 to have only recent measurements (expected them to be available only during one cycle of observation)
- values > 0.0 to keep the observation during some time and refresh the clearings after

---

Question : How do you think is it possible to have the clearings present only when the object is detected ?

---

Code:

```
x_obstacle_clearing_layer:
  enabled: true
  observation_sources: x_object_clearing_cloud
  combination_method: 0

x_object_clearing_cloud:
  sensor_frame: base_footprint
  data_type: PointCloud2
  topic: /detect_x_object/object
  expected_update_rate: 2.0
  observation_persistence: 1.0
  marking: false
  clearing: true
  raytrace_range: 5.3
  obstacle_range: 4.8
  min_obstacle_height: -2.0
  max_obstacle_height: 2.0
```

---

Thank you !

P.S.: Working with **ROS Kinetic**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292822/why-the-clearing-stays-permanent-in-obstacle-costmap,-when-0-(overwrite)-combination-method-is-applied?/) by [Andrei Pasnicenco](https://answers.ros.org/users/35589/andrei-pasnicenco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-05-31

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is to reset each value of **costmap** to **NO_INFORMATION** before each update.

More info :
https://answers.ros.org/question/165726/obstacle_layer-updates-areas-out-of-sight/?answer=175137#post-id-175137

---

Originally posted by [Andrei Pasnicenco](https://answers.ros.org/users/35589/andrei-pasnicenco/) with karma: 56 on 2018-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0